# JavaFx scene lookup returning null

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

```
Button btn = new Button("ohot");
btn.setId("testId");
itemSection.getChildren().add(btn);
Node nds = itemSection.lookup("‪#‎testId‬");
```

What is wrong with above code?? I am getting nds=null it should be btn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Lookups in conjunction with applyCSS*

[Lookups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) are based on [CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html). So CSS needs to be applied to the scene for you to be able to lookup items in the scene. See the [`applyCSS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--) documentation for more information.  To get accurate results from your lookup, you might also want to invoke [layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#layout--), as the layout operation can effect scene graph attributes.

So you could do this:

```
Button btn = new Button("ohot");
btn.setId("testId");
itemSection.getChildren().add(btn);
itemSection.applyCss();
itemSection.layout();
Node nds = itemSection.lookup("‪#‎testId‬");
```

*Alternate lookup after showing a stage*

Note that some operations in JavaFX, such as initially [showing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#show--) a Stage or waiting for a [pulse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1107438) to occur, will implicitly execute a CSS application, but most operations will not.

So you could also do this:

```
Button btn = new Button("ohot");
btn.setId("testId");
itemSection.getChildren().add(btn);
stage.setScene(new Scene(itemSection);
stage.show();
Node nds = itemSection.lookup("‪#‎testId‬");
```

*On CSS based lookups VS explicit references*

Storing and using explicit references in your code is often preferred to using lookups.  Unlike a lookup, using an explicit reference is type safe and does not depend upon a CSS application.  Generating explicit references can also be facilitated by using JavaFX and FXML with the [@FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers) annotation for type-safe reference injection.  However, both lookup and explicit reference approaches have valid use cases, so it is a really just a matter of using the right approach at the right time.